# Как нарисовать и закрасить массив шестиугольников в python используя matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

У меня есть класс POLYGON, каждый объект этого класса имеет в качестве параметров координаты вершин многоугольника (шестиугольника в данном случае) и параметр "value", который отображает, к примеру, значение какой-либо функции в данном шестиугольнике. Нужное количество шестиугольников в заданных точках я создаю без проблем.
Вопрос в том, как нарисовать их, при этом так, чтобы каждый шестиугольник был закрашен в соответствии со значением параметра "value" и нарисовать также colorbar. Все это, используя библиотеку matplotlib.
Пример, как должно получиться - на картинке.

[image: Пример закраски]

Класс POLYGON:

```
class POLYGON:
    def __init__(self,xc,yc,znum,value,st):
        self.xc=xc #координата центра на оси абсцисс 
        self.yc=yc #координата центра на оси ординат
        self.znum=znum #для нумерации и поиска
        self.value=value #значение функции в данном шестиугольнике
        self.st=st #размер под ключ
        self.r=st/2 #радиус вписанной окружности
        self.R=st/pow(3,.5) #радиус описанной окружности
        self.a=self.R #сторона шестиугольника
        self.points=[(self.xc+self.a/2,self.yc+self.r), #массив координат вершин
                (self.xc+self.R,self.yc),
                (self.xc+self.a/2,self.yc-self.r),
                (self.xc-self.a/2,self.yc-self.r),
                (self.xc-self.R,self.yc),
                (self.xc-self.a/2,self.yc+self.r)]
```

Я могу их нарисовать, используя pylab:

```
def drawPolygons (axes,points,color):
    """
    Рисование многоугольника
    """
    polygon_1 = pylab.Polygon (points,
                               facecolor=color,
                               edgecolor='black')
    axes.add_patch (polygon_1)

#Допустим, есть массив координат центров шестиугольников
xc=[0, 10.392304845413264, 20.784609690826528]
yc=[0, -6.0, -12.0]
poly=[] #Массив, содержащий объекты шестиугольников
for i in range(len(xc)):
    #Инициализация шестиугольника с данными координатами центра 
    #Со случайным параметром "value"
    pol=POLYGON(xc[i],yc[i],'znum',random.randint(0,20),12)
    poly.append(pol)

pylab.xlim (-50, 50)
pylab.ylim (-50, 50)
axes = pylab.gca()
axes.set_aspect("equal")    

for i in range(len(poly)):
    a=poly[i].points
    drawPolygons (axes,a,(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.7))

pylab.show()
```

Однако, в этом случае приходится явно задавать цвет. Как сделать автоматическую генерацию цветов для любых colormaps из matplotlib, зная значения "value" для всех шестиугольников, и как сделать colorbar не понимаю.

Comment: @MaxU Добавил класс и задание объектов

Comment: @MaxU извиняюсь, подправил, теперь должно работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

class POLYGON:
    def __init__(self,xc,yc,znum,value,st):
        self.xc=xc #координата центра на оси абсцисс 
        self.yc=yc #координата центра на оси ординат
        self.znum=znum #для нумерации и поиска
        self.value=value #значение функции в данном шестиугольнике
        self.st=st #размер под ключ
        self.r=st/2 #радиус вписанной окружности
        self.R=st/pow(3,.5) #радиус описанной окружности
        self.a=self.R #сторона шестиугольника
        self.points=[(self.xc+self.a/2,self.yc+self.r), #массив координат вершин
                (self.xc+self.R,self.yc),
                (self.xc+self.a/2,self.yc-self.r),
                (self.xc-self.a/2,self.yc-self.r),
                (self.xc-self.R,self.yc),
                (self.xc-self.a/2,self.yc+self.r)]

    def draw(self, ax=None, cmap=None, norm=None, edgecolor='black'):
        ax = ax if ax is not None else plt.gca()
        if cmap is None:
            cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')
        if norm is None:
            norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(0, 20)
        polygon_1 = plt.Polygon(self.points,
                                facecolor=cmap(norm(self.value)),
                                edgecolor=edgecolor)
        ax.add_patch(polygon_1)

xc=[0, 10.392304845413264, 20.784609690826528]
yc=[0, -6.0, -12.0]

polys = [POLYGON(x, y, 'znum', random.randint(0,20), 12) for x,y in zip(xc, yc)]

cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet') # or any other one
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(0, 20)

ax = plt.gca()
_ = [pol.draw(ax=ax, cmap=cmap, norm=norm) for pol in polys]            
plt.xlim (-50, 50)
plt.ylim (-50, 50)
ax.set_aspect("equal")    
plt.show()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо, встроил в свою программу, все работает, все понял) Думаю, с colorbar сам справлюсь)